# execute/debug a unit test "method" in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

is there any way to execute/debug a unit test "method" in c#. I m new to unit testing and there are lot of test methods in our file. I needed to test one among them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put a breakpoint inside the unit test method and then use <kbd>Ctrl+R+T</kbd>. This will run the unit test in debug mode and the breakpoint will be hit. Alternatively to using the keyboard shortcut you could open the Test Explorer Window and then locate the unit test you want to run, right click on it and select Debug Unit Test.

Comment: Thank you darin. It works and really helpful. Im using resharper now which provides a ball kind of symbol to each method and i can directly execute from there.

Comment: @user2949346, glad I could have helped. By the way if my answer helped you resolve the problem you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work